# How to extract filename in path in cell excel (formul)?

Tags: excel-formula

I have paths in Excel column and I want extract filename in other cell without VBA.

```
/where/is/my/path/filename.txt
```

I would like extract "filename.txt"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I share with you my finds.

I find this site :
https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1431-excel-extract-filename-from-full-path.html

```
=MID(A1,FIND("*",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\","*",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",""))))+1,LEN(A1))
```

But doesn't work on french Excel that's why I translate for French users :

```
=STXT(A1;CHERCHE("$";SUBSTITUE(A1;"/";"$";NBCAR(A1)-NBCAR(SUBSTITUE(A1;"/";""))))+1;NBCAR(A1))
```

I change "\" to "/" because I have unix path.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a concise solution. It splits the full path by "/" and then grabs the last occurrence.

```
=CHOOSECOLS(TEXTSPLIT(A1,"/"),-1)
```

If you want to get just the file path as well, assuming you put the filename in column C:

```
=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-LEN(C1))
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help:

```
var url = "/where/is/my/path/filename.txt";
var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
alert(filename);
```